# pymssql not returning result data

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm experiencing issues when running the `pymssql` package (version 1.0.2) on linux. It would seem that I can connect successfully and issue SQL statements to the server, but queries return blank results. I've confirmed that `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements work without issue, but even when I create a new table and insert data into it queries against this table return blank/empty results. Here's the code I'm using:

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='#', user='#', password='#', database='#')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tblFoo')
>>> print cur.fetchone()
None
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tblFoo')
>>> cur.fetchall()
[]
>>> cur.execute('SELECT GETDATE()')
>>> print cur.fetchone()
None
```

I've also tried using the `_mssql` package, and making `_mssql` connect to the database via `freetds` using a global config, but I'm getting the same issue.

Connecting and querying via the `tds` command line tool ***does*** return results as expected.

I'm using Python 2.6.6 on redhat, and I'm installing `pymssql` via buildout. I've also tried installing globally using `pip`, and I've also tried using the latest dev version of `pymssql`.

Has anyone else experienced this or similar issues? Any advice on how to debug this problem? I'm limited to using SQL Server for this project, and I'm unable to use `pyodbc`.

**Update:**

Further investigation shows we're using `freetds` 0.91, which seems to cause problems with `pymssql` 1.0.2, however I'm still seeing problems when building with the latest version of `pymssql`.

Comment: could you add some code?  how to know that you got blank results?

Comment: @RomanPekar I'm not sure it would be worth it, but I'll update the question with further info.

Comment: thanks for asking, pmod's answer solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

This was some incompatibility issue between freetds 0.91 and pymssql 1.0.X (see [bugreport here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pymssql/+bug/918896))

However this was fixed with the newest release of pymssql (I upgraded to 2.0.1 and this problem was gone - exact name of package: pymssql-2.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg). With python setuptools now it's easy as:

```
easy_install --upgrade pymssql
```

(Don't forget that python-dev and freetds-dev debs should be installed beforehand)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this patch:

```
diff --git a/mssqldbmodule.c b/mssqldbmodule.c
index 151bc2c..7081715 100644
--- a/mssqldbmodule.c
+++ b/mssqldbmodule.c
@@ -1934,12 +1934,12 @@ PyObject *get_result(_mssql_connection *conn) {

  // find a result set that has at least one column
conn->last_dbresults = SUCCEED;
-   while (conn->last_dbresults == SUCCEED &&
-           (conn->num_columns = dbnumcols(conn->dbproc)) <= 0) {
+   do {
        Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
        conn->last_dbresults = dbresults(conn->dbproc);
        Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
-   }
+   } while (conn->last_dbresults == SUCCEED &&
+           (conn->num_columns = dbnumcols(conn->dbproc)) <= 0);

    check_cancel_and_raise(conn->last_dbresults, conn);
```

http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2013q3/028493.html

https://gist.github.com/msabramo/6501240